# load qr code link in UIwebview swift iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiwebview, qr-code

hello everybody i have a webview *VViewController.swift* and
QRCode Scanner *QRRViewController.swift* how to load the QR Code if its url to a web view direct and not to safari ?

VVCiewcontroller.swift

```
  import UIKit
class VViewController: UIViewController {



 @IBOutlet weak var WWebView: UIWebView!

 var QRLink:String!



 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    var url = NSURL(string: QRLink)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    WWebView.loadRequest(request)
  }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

QRRViewController.swift lok like this 
this code load the Qr code URL to safari and not to web view

.......

```
if metadataObj.type == AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode {
let barCodeObject = videoPreviewLayer?.transformedMetadataObjectForMetadataObject(metadataObj as AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject) as! AVMetadataMachineReadableCodeObject

qrCodeFrameView?.frame = barCodeObject.bounds;

if metadataObj.stringValue != nil {
  messageLabel.text = metadataObj.stringValue
    //if the result is url...
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: metadataObj.stringValue)!)

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you move from the QR view controller to the web views view controller, use the prepare for segue method to pass the link to the next view.

Add this to the QR view controller

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {

    // Create a variable that you want to send
    var QRLink = self.QRLink

    // Create a new variable to store the instance of PlayerTableViewController
    let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as VViewController
    destinationVC.QRLink = QRLink
}
```

Dont forget, you need to also add the variable in the webviews controller to store the QR link.

VVCiewcontroller.swift

```
  import UIKit
class VViewController: UIViewController {

private var QRLink: String

 @IBOutlet weak var WWebView: UIWebView!

 var QRLink:String!



 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()



    var url = NSURL(string: QRLink)
    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    WWebView.loadRequest(request)
  }

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

  }
@IBAction func goBack(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
  }
}
```

Comment: i tray everything but i am very new in Xcode and did you know something examples like this in github or somewhere  thx a lot for your answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are able to retrieve the string from your qr code reader function,
, also that you have a webview, so try this:

```
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: "THE URL FROM QRCode")
        wvScreen.loadRequest(request)
```